# What's the difference between stopping and closing a download?

Tags: rtorrent

In *rtorrent* there are two key combinations:

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>d</kbd>  Stop an active download or remove a stopped download.
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>k</kbd>  Stop and close the files of an active download.

What does closing a download mean? What's the difference between closing and stopping+closing?

Answer (score 4):

### The Difference

[<sub>Source BitTorrent Explained</sub>](http://www.howtogeek.com/141257/htg-explains-how-does-bittorrent-work/)

The **rTorrent** software is a **BitTorrent** client. BitTorrent is a peer-to-peer protocol, which means that the computers in a BitTorrent “swarm” (a group of computers downloading and uploading the same torrent) transfer data between each other without the need for a central server.

Traditionally, a computer joins a BitTorrent swarm by loading a .torrent file into a BitTorrent client. The BitTorrent client contacts a “tracker” specified in the .torrent file. The tracker is a special server that keeps track of the connected computers. The tracker shares their IP addresses with other BitTorrent clients in the swarm, allowing them to connect to each other.

This means the `.torrent` file contains the IP addresses, etc. of other clients in the "swarm" that have parts of the file(s) you're downloading. You need this file to complete a full download of any files in the network. So the `.torrent` is the "tracker" (or pointer) and the file you'll download,  per the information in the `.torrent`, is the "content".

1. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> means to stop active downloads and
   remove stopped downloads

   So utilizing the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> option means:

   - to stop (or pause) an active download of an incomplete (or
     partially) downloaded [content] file but leave the `.torrent` file in place so it can finish this operation later.
   - if an incomplete file is in the stopped or paused state already
     when this option is utilized, then it'll remove that partially
     downloaded file entirely and the correlated .`torrent` file and this operation will NOT be able to finish this operation later—you'll need to load the `.torrent` file again into the client to download that [content] file.
2. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd> means to stop and close a torrent and its files

   So utilizing the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd> option means:

   - to stop an active download of an incomplete (or
     partially) downloaded [content] file and to close any connections to this file in the network but leave the `.torrent` file in place so it can finish the download operation later.

---

### Additional Resources

1. Have a look at [How BitTorrent
   Works](http://www.howtogeek.com/141257/htg-explains-how-does-bittorrent-work/)
   for a full explanation.
2. Here's a link to [rTorrent Quick Reference
   Card](https://tekguru.files.wordpress.com/2009/05/rtorrent_ref.pdf).
3. This is explained in the [rTorrent Wiki User
   Guide](https://github.com/rakshasa/rtorrent/wiki/User-Guide) as
   shown below (the `^k` and `^d` options).

   [image]

Comment: Thank you! So after pressing Ctrl-S once, network connections and local files are still kept open?

Comment: From my interpretation pressing the Ctrl+D once will stop or pause all currently downloading processes but will also delete any that are stopped including the correlated .torrent file.  If you want to ensure you can kick those off later, I'd press the Ctrl+K.  If you have a way to test without a bunch of critical files, I'd suggest doing that as the rTorrent documentation that I found is not real clear and this is just a function of the BitTorrent client software so there's no standard I'm aware of these keys need to conform to. I don't use rTorrent but will gladly test to confirm if you want?

Comment: @PetrPudlák .... Did this write up from the source help clarify anything for you in the format it's provided with the referenced material and other resources? I'm curious to get an update so we can get this handled accordingly to finalize if that's possible. When you get time, let me know—it's an old answer I posted so just curious if it's helpful or what you think. I'm debating in my head so curious to hear your feedback first just in case.